# ionic buttons and side-menu disabled

Tags: ionic-framework, side-menu

Im currently working on an ionic app integrated with capacitor. I have 3 pages connected with sidemenu. when i first open the page all the buttons are working properly. But when I navigate to other page and come back to the first page using side-menu, side-menu button and all other buttons are disabled. Same thing happens with all the three pages.
Here's my code for side menu in all app.html:

```
<ion-app>
 <ion-menu side="start" content-id="main-content" >
   <ion-header>
     <ion-toolbar translucent>
       <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
     </ion-toolbar>
   </ion-header>
   <ion-content>
     <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            //navigate to other page-A
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            //navigate to other page-B
        </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
 </ion-menu>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please show us how you are navigating to the next pages? Please add that part in your question above and also any error log you are getting.

Comment: `this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['page-A']);
    });`                                                                                                                                            Thankyou. On clicking any item in the sidemenu, I call a function which navigates as shown above. when i return to the first page, all the buttons are just diabled, there is no error log.